# Calculate distance from one GPS co-ordinate to another?

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I am trying to create an Android app which gives me my Location change updates for every 2 meters I move. The Api I am using is:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, (float)2, locationListener);
```

I am able to calculate the distance between two co-ordinates with the haversine formula.
I want to know how much distance I moved latitudinaly and longitudinaly.
What I mean is, I want to know `delta(x)` and `delta(y)` from the previous location in metres. I have with me `currentLat`, `currentLong`, `previousLat`, `previousLong`.

For example: I am getting the following GPS co-ordinates in my app:

```
Latitude: 12.9812007  Longitude: 77.74348163
Latitude: 12.98119122  Longitude: 77.74348192
Latitude: 12.98118058  Longitude: 77.74348131
Latitude: 12.9812041  Longitude: 77.74350371
Latitude: 12.98119337  Longitude: 77.74350154
Latitude: 12.98117935  Longitude: 77.74350156
Latitude: 12.9811742  Longitude: 77.74349111
Latitude: 12.98116478  Longitude: 77.74348577
Latitude: 12.98114454  Longitude: 77.7434776
Latitude: 12.98113244  Longitude: 77.74347141
Latitude: 12.98112247  Longitude: 77.74346629
Latitude: 12.98111381  Longitude: 77.74347568<br/>
Latitude: 12.98112889  Longitude: 77.74348118
Latitude: 12.9811384  Longitude: 77.74348133
Latitude: 12.98114325  Longitude: 77.74346866
Latitude: 12.9811306  Longitude: 77.74345533
Latitude: 12.98112043  Longitude: 77.74344925
Latitude: 12.98110867  Longitude: 77.74344979
Latitude: 12.98109571  Longitude: 77.74345256
Latitude: 12.98110153  Longitude: 77.74346184
Latitude: 12.98111135  Longitude: 77.74346482
Latitude: 12.98112283  Longitude: 77.74346764
Latitude: 12.98113165  Longitude: 77.74347133
Latitude: 12.98114311  Longitude: 77.74347645
Latitude: 12.98115332  Longitude: 77.74348057
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Putting this as a comment because this is just a workaround : if you set up a good method to compute the real distance, keep using it to get what you want, and for your delta(x) pass in 2 long of 0... For delta(y) pass in 2 lats of 0 .... For what it's worth... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know latitudinal difference and longitudinal difference separately between two locations then you should try the solution given below.

If you have

```
currentLat = 12.98119122 currentLong = 77.74348192
```

and

```
previousLat = 12.9812007 previousLong = 77.74348163
```

Then to find `latDifference` use,

```
haversine(double currentLat, double previousLong, double previousLat, double previousLong)
```

This will give you latitudinal difference between two locations, and to find `longDifference` use,

```
haversine(double previousLat, double currentLong, double previousLat, double previousLong)
```

I assume you know haversine formula as you have said in your question.

**Edit:**

To find latDifference use same value for current longitude and previous longitude

and to find longDifference use same value for current latitude and previous latitude in haversine formula.